# jquery href question

Tags: jquery

I moved all my pdf files into another folder but I don't want to have to change all the link  and adding pdf/ in the href. is there a faster and simpler way to do this?

i.e.

```
<a href="test.pdf">test</a>
```

change to

```
<a href="pdf/test.pdf">test</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `<base>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
  <base href="pdf"/>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="test.pdf">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice trick, But this will work for all anchors in the page not just with href contains .pdf

Comment: this will break other references (like images) that are on the same page.

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy, @Pekka -- Okay, I know this is pedantic, but the question didn't mention other links :-)

Comment: That's cool, I had never heard of that before. But there is probably a reason for that!

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow it's useful if all your links share a long common path, in particular if you're writing a page by hand. I guess it would be useful too if your links were insanely long for generated pages too, but I've never seen it used to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

If your document is stored on a *nix system, I recommend using `sed` to fix the links:

```
sed 's/\"\(.*\.pdf\)\"/\"pdf\/\1\"/' index.html > new_index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible with jQuery, but you're much better off fixing the actual links, so users with JavaScript turned off, bots etc. can access the content and don't run into a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should fix the links to work correctly without JavaScript, but as a though experiment this is how you could do it in jQuery:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').not('a[href^="http"]').attr('href', function(i, val) { return 'pdf/' + val });
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/XRfZP/

thanks to @Sime

Comment: @Phil each() is not needed: `$(...).attr('href', function(i,v) { retrun 'pdf/' + v; });`

Comment: @Sime Yer I guess old habits die hard.

Comment: Actually, the `attr()` method would be the more correct of the two. Your first one would likely fail because the `href` property will probably give you the full domain path, while the `.attr()` should just give you the actual attribute value. The first one should use `pathname` instead.

Comment: @patrick Yes you're correct I just tested it. I will remove it from the answer.